# How to filter a name from a sentence in database?

Tags: mysql

I want to query string from a field from my database. For example: Field "Address", value "Toul Kork District, Phnom Penh". Want I want to get is only "Phnom Penh". I know that my sql is not allow to select only this string from the field. So, what is the good way to do that?

Comment: Do you know in advance all the possible fields (as in all possible cities) you want to get from the database?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Address,
    LOCATE(Value,Address),
    LENGTH(Address) - LENGTH(Value));
```

[`POSITION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position) function is synonim for `LOCATE`. You can use `POSITION` function as well :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Address,
        LOCATE(Value IN Address),
        LENGTH(Address) - LENGTH(Value));
```

In static variable it's looks like :

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Toul Kork District,Phnom Penh',
    LOCATE('Phnom Penh','Toul Kork District,Phnom Penh'),
    LENGTH('Toul Kork District,Phnom Penh') - LENGTH('Phnom Penh'));
```

`Result : Phnom Penh`

Comment: RubahMalam- The LOCATE method is not defined! How to solve this?

Comment: @TumLina Try `POSITION` function. It's similiar to `LOCATE`.

Comment: I have no idea why I can't use Select substr in my laravel controler, It says undefined SELECT SUBTR.
Please help me out!

Comment: @TumLina Please edit your question and provide the code, and what you have done so far.

Comment: $client = Client::select(substr('address',
                                locate('Phnom Penh','address'),
                                LENGTH('address') - LENGTH('Phnom Penh')))->get();
This is the code I have try.